# What is the language format returned by Map.getSupportedMapDisplayLanguages()

Tags: android, here-api

I'm working on an app using Here API Android Premium and want to show users a list of languages to select from for use with `Map.setMapSecondaryDisplayLanguage()` from [Class Map](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/Map.html#setMapSecondaryDisplayLanguage-java.util.Locale-).

The same Map class has a function to provide a list of all supported languages `Map.getSupportedMapDisplayLanguages()`, which should be perfect.

```java
List<String> mapTLangs = map.getSupportedMapDisplayLanguages();
sLogger.e(mapTLangs);
```

```
E/LanguageMenu: [AFR, ALB, ARA, ARM, ASM, AZE, BAQ, BEL, BEN, BOS, BUL, CAT, CHI, CHT ...
```

The values returned by `getSupportedMapDisplayLanguages()` are three letter acronyms and I can't find what format they're in.

Most of them are found in the [ISO 639-2/B" listings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) but some of them like CHT are not in any of the listings there.

Does anyone know how to convert these TLA's to the Locale needed for `Map.setMapSecondaryDisplayLanguage()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for this list of 2-letter and 3-letter language codes for map labels: [Map Label Languages](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/coverage-label-languages.html)

The 3-letter language codes are based on MARC codes (which are also the basis for ISO 639-2), but with some Navteq additions like CHT for Traditional Chinese (used in Taiwan and Hongkong), whereas CHI is used for Simplified Chinese (used in mainland China).

While country codes look similar for being 3-letter acronyms as well, they make up a completely different list.

Comment: Thanks, I never found that page. What an annoyingly arbitrary list they've used! It seems in this example CHT is either/both "Chinese Taiwan" and "Hong Kong Chinese"!

Comment: Just for a little more inconsistency, the setMapSecondaryDisplayLanguage() takes a Locale bu the (presumably) matching getMapSecondaryDisplayLanguage()  returns a MARC code! So I can't easily get the current setting and set it again directly!

Comment: @coronafire, I agree on both. There is actually a lot of documentation, but hard to find, and the functions should use a consistent data type. CHT is ok though, as it's the same written language used in both Hong Kong and Taiwan.

Answer (score 0):

That´s are the 3 letter acronyms for countries (ISO 3166 ALPHA-3), you can see the equivalent for the country in this list:

https://laendercode.net/en/3-letter-list.html

https://www.worldatlas.com/aatlas/ctycodes.htm

---

```
AFG
Afghanistan
ALA
Aland Islands
ALB
Albania
DZA
Algeria
ASM
American Samoa
AND
Andorra
AGO
Angola
AIA
Anguilla
ATA
Antarctica
ATG
Antigua and Barbuda
ARG
Argentina
ARM
Armenia
ABW
Aruba
AUS
Australia
AUT
Austria
AZE
Azerbaijan
BHS
Bahamas
BHR
Bahrain
BGD
Bangladesh
BRB
Barbados
BLR
Belarus
BEL
Belgium
BLZ
Belize
BEN
Benin
BMU
Bermuda
BTN
Bhutan
BOL
Bolivia
BES
Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba
BIH
Bosnia and Herzegovina
BWA
Botswana
BVT
Bouvet Island
BRA
Brazil
IOT
British Indian Ocean Territory
VGB
British Virgin Islands
BRN
Brunei
BGR
Bulgaria
BFA
Burkina Faso
BDI
Burundi
KHM
Cambodia
CMR
Cameroon
CAN
Canada
CPV
Cape Verde
CYM
Cayman Islands
CAF
Central African Republic
TCD
Chad
CHL
Chile
CHN
China
CXR
Christmas Island
CCK
Cocos Islands
COL
Colombia
COM
Comoros
COK
Cook Islands
CRI
Costa Rica
HRV
Croatia
CUB
Cuba
CUW
Curacao
CYP
Cyprus
CZE
Czech Republic
COD
Democratic Republic of the Congo
DNK
Denmark
DJI
Djibouti
DMA
Dominica
DOM
Dominican Republic
TLS
East Timor
ECU
Ecuador
EGY
Egypt
SLV
El Salvador
GNQ
Equatorial Guinea
ERI
Eritrea
EST
Estonia
ETH
Ethiopia
FLK
Falkland Islands
FRO
Faroe Islands
FJI
Fiji
FIN
Finland
FRA
France
GUF
French Guiana
PYF
French Polynesia
ATF
French Southern Territories
GAB
Gabon
GMB
Gambia
GEO
Georgia
DEU
Germany
GHA
Ghana
GIB
Gibraltar
GRC
Greece
GRL
Greenland
GRD
Grenada
GLP
Guadeloupe
GUM
Guam
GTM
Guatemala
GGY
Guernsey
GIN
Guinea
GNB
Guinea-Bissau
GUY
Guyana
HTI
Haiti
HMD
Heard Island and McDonald Islands
HND
Honduras
HKG
Hong Kong
HUN
Hungary
ISL
Iceland
IND
India
IDN
Indonesia
IRN
Iran
IRQ
Iraq
IRL
Ireland
IMN
Isle of Man
ISR
Israel
ITA
Italy
CIV
Ivory Coast
JAM
Jamaica
JPN
Japan
JEY
Jersey
JOR
Jordan
KAZ
Kazakhstan
KEN
Kenya
KIR
Kiribati
XKX
Kosovo
KWT
Kuwait
KGZ
Kyrgyzstan
LAO
Laos
LVA
Latvia
LBN
Lebanon
LSO
Lesotho
LBR
Liberia
LBY
Libya
LIE
Liechtenstein
LTU
Lithuania
LUX
Luxembourg
MAC
Macao
MKD
Macedonia
MDG
Madagascar
MWI
Malawi
MYS
Malaysia
MDV
Maldives
MLI
Mali
MLT
Malta
MHL
Marshall Islands
MTQ
Martinique
MRT
Mauritania
MUS
Mauritius
MYT
Mayotte
MEX
Mexico
FSM
Micronesia
MDA
Moldova
MCO
Monaco
MNG
Mongolia
MNE
Montenegro
MSR
Montserrat
MAR
Morocco
MOZ
Mozambique
MMR
Myanmar
NAM
Namibia
NRU
Nauru
NPL
Nepal
NLD
Netherlands
ANT
Netherlands Antilles
NCL
New Caledonia
NZL
New Zealand
NIC
Nicaragua
NER
Niger
NGA
Nigeria
NIU
Niue
NFK
Norfolk Island
PRK
North Korea
MNP
Northern Mariana Islands
NOR
Norway
OMN
Oman
PAK
Pakistan
PLW
Palau
PSE
Palestinian Territory
PAN
Panama
PNG
Papua New Guinea
PRY
Paraguay
PER
Peru
PHL
Philippines
PCN
Pitcairn
POL
Poland
PRT
Portugal
PRI
Puerto Rico
QAT
Qatar
COG
Republic of the Congo
REU
Reunion
ROU
Romania
RUS
Russia
RWA
Rwanda
BLM
Saint Barthelemy
SHN
Saint Helena
KNA
Saint Kitts and Nevis
LCA
Saint Lucia
MAF
Saint Martin
SPM
Saint Pierre and Miquelon
VCT
Saint Vincent and the Grenadines
WSM
Samoa
SMR
San Marino
STP
Sao Tome and Principe
SAU
Saudi Arabia
SEN
Senegal
SRB
Serbia
SCG
Serbia and Montenegro
SYC
Seychelles
SLE
Sierra Leone
SGP
Singapore
SXM
Sint Maarten
SVK
Slovakia
SVN
Slovenia
SLB
Solomon Islands
SOM
Somalia
ZAF
South Africa
SGS
South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands
KOR
South Korea
SSD
South Sudan
ESP
Spain
LKA
Sri Lanka
SDN
Sudan
SUR
Suriname
SJM
Svalbard and Jan Mayen
SWZ
Swaziland
SWE
Sweden
CHE
Switzerland
SYR
Syria
TWN
Taiwan
TJK
Tajikistan
TZA
Tanzania
THA
Thailand
TGO
Togo
TKL
Tokelau
TON
Tonga
TTO
Trinidad and Tobago
TUN
Tunisia
TUR
Turkey
TKM
Turkmenistan
TCA
Turks and Caicos Islands
TUV
Tuvalu
VIR
U.S. Virgin Islands
UGA
Uganda
UKR
Ukraine
ARE
United Arab Emirates
GBR
United Kingdom
USA
United States
UMI
United States Minor Outlying Islands
URY
Uruguay
UZB
Uzbekistan
VUT
Vanuatu
VAT
Vatican
VEN
Venezuela
VNM
Vietnam
WLF
Wallis and Futuna
ESH
Western Sahara
YEM
Yemen
ZMB
Zambia
ZWE
Zimbabwe
```

Comment: Thanks but in this case I think @ctrlw has the correct answer judging by the provided link. I don't think here-api actually specifies cities, just languages